# how to save to a already made file python not working

Tags: python, save

I ahve a simple text editor program. Where you can click save as and you can choose where to save that file. But if you click the save button to save to that file I get his error:

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Here is the saved and saved as part of the code. I have a variable avalivle to all fucntion(self.Saved):

```
def Save(self):
    File = open(self.Saved,"w") --Where error occurs 
    if File is None:
        return
    self.Cont.insert(END,"<fg='" + self.FontColor + "'>")
    self.Cont.insert(END,"<bg='" + self.BackgroundColor + "'>")
    Content=self.Cont.get(1.0,END)
    File.write(Content)
    File.close()

def SaveAs(self):
    File = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    if File is None:
        return
    self.Saved = File
    self.Cont.insert(END,"<fg='" + self.FontColor + "'>")
    self.Cont.insert(END,"<bg='" + self.BackgroundColor + "'>")
    Content = self.Cont.get(1.0,END)
    File.write(Content)
    File.close()
```

Comment: What is the value in `self.Saved` when you run: `File = open(self.Saved,"w")` ? Second, where is `asksaveasfile()` defined ? and last, what is returned from `self.Cont.get(1.0,END)` ?

Comment: @alfasin    The value is changed to self.Saved = File when you click save as. But when you work on the file and click save it gives me the error I put up above. I did not show that part of the script because that is not causing the error I have narrowed it down to this code.

Comment: BTW: there is the Python rule - use lowercase for variable name.

Comment: In error message is number of line with problem - mark this line in your code.

Comment: I suspect that when the code in `save()` is called: `File = open(self.Saved,"w")` the variable `self.Saved` is not defined.

Comment: @alfasin I knew that. I just can't figure out how to store that file correctly in the variable.

Comment: Set `self.Saved = None` in `__init__` and check `if self.Saved` before you open file in `Save()`

Comment: @cdw100100 you should get from the user the filename if it doesn't exist, sent it to the function as one of the arguments, and when you open the file, use the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Set `self.Saved = None` in `__init__` and do

```
def Save(self):
    if not self.Saved:
        self.SaveAs()
    else:
        File = open(self.Saved,"w")  # Where error occurs 
        if File is None:
            return
        self.Cont.insert(END,"<fg='" + self.FontColor + "'>")
        self.Cont.insert(END,"<bg='" + self.BackgroundColor + "'>")
        Content=self.Cont.get(1.0,END)
        File.write(Content)
        File.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** use `asksaveasfilename` to get filename

```
def SaveAs(self):

    filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    if not filename:
        return
    self.Saved = filename

    File = open(self.Saved,"w")  
    if File is None:
       return
    self.Cont.insert(END,"<fg='" + self.FontColor + "'>")
    self.Cont.insert(END,"<bg='" + self.BackgroundColor + "'>")
    Content = self.Cont.get(1.0,END)
    File.write(Content)
    File.close()
```

Comment: This helpful but does not answer my question...
I am asking how would I store that file in self.Saved so i can save to that file later?

Comment: `asksaveasfile` give you only filename and you have to open it for writting.

Comment: But I am opening the file for writing with the File = open(self.Saved,"w")

Comment: Moment. In `SaveAs()`: you have to use `asksaveasfilename` in place of `asksaveasfile` to get filename and keep it in `self.Saved`, then you have to open file, write data and close file. In `Save()`: if you have filename in `self.Saved` you have to open file, write data and close file.

Comment: In `self.Saved` you keep only filename - not opened file.

Comment: How do I open the file then? I have tried open(self.Saved,"w") and I t seems to be not working.

Comment: Remove `mode='w'` - `asksaveasfilename` doesn't use it.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\Basic Notpad 0.3.pyw", line 40, in Save
    File = open(self.Saved,"w")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: Did you use `asksaveasfilename` as in my answer - see above ? This error means you still keep opened file in `self.Saved` instead of filename.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works in stead of what I had I would like a better explanation I like to completely understand something before I implement it into the official program.

Comment: First: `self.Saved = None` in `__init__` and you have variable `self.Saved` at the beginning - you can't get error `variable not exists`. And you know that file wasn't saved because you have no filename in `self.Saved` - I would call this variable `self.Filename`.

Comment: When you click `SaveAs` it execute `asksaveasfilename` and you can choose filename. You will get that filename in variable `filename`. If you `cancel` that window than you get empty string in `filename`.

Comment: In `if not filename:` you check if you got empty string. If you have filename then you can keep it in `self.Saved` . Now you have filename so you can open file for writting. In `if File is None:` you check if file was opened correctly. Then you can write text from window in file `File.write(Content)` and you close file. If you don't close file some text can be unsave in file.

Comment: In `Save()` first you check if you have filename in `self.Saved` - if you don't than it calls `SaveAs()` - it will ask for filename, and do rest of job. If you have filename in `self.Saved` it will not ask for filename, it open file for writting, write data and close file. That's all.

Comment: `Save()` and `SaveAs()` are very similar so eventually you could make one function with extra argument `Save(self, ask_for_filename=False)`